# DBVisualizer/SQL Explorer will not connect to the right DB instance

Tags: sql-server, eclipse, dbvisualizer

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server instance in DBVisualizer on ubuntu and for some reason unknown to me it incessantly connects to the wrong instance. The target is a Windows Server that is running multiple instances of SQL Server on it. I am trying to connect to it using the following string:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://srv\sql2:1433;DatabaseName=CloudServices
```

However quite amusingly, it continuously connects to srv\sql1 even though my connection string points to **sql2** and not **sql1**. I can connect to the right db instance (**sql2**) using SSMS on Windows perfectly fine.

I am having the same issue when I try to connect to this DB using SQL Explorer in Eclipse

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still need the answer for this but try using this connection string in DBvisulizer.

```
jdbc:sqlserver://srv\sql2:1433;Instance=INSERTYOURINSTANCEHERE;DatabaseName=CloudServices
```

Comment: Hi Dave, No luck. The following is my 'Resource' tag in the context.xml for Tomcat
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" maxActive="8" maxIdle="4" name="jdbc/test" password="xxx" username="xxx" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:sqlserver://srv\sql2:1433;Instance=sql2;DatabaseName=testdb"/>

Answer (score 0):

Port 1433 is the static port of the default instance.  Try connecting to the redirector on port 1434 and specifying the instance name property in your connection string.